# Script not taking into account anchor location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The script changes the background color of a div when you scroll down in the modal. I've got an anchor but the script activates the background color change as if the anchor was `top:0;`. It doesn't like `top:30%;`.

`#anchor-point {
    top: 30%;
    position:absolute;
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is correct.
What's not is your JS:

You declare

```
var targetOffset = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;
```

at the beginning of your script, when $('#anchor-point') is not yet displayed. Thus, the browser thinks its offset is 0.

If you wait for the element to be displayed to get its offset, then it works.

A very simple fix in your case is not to use a temp variable, but do the computation right when needed:

```
if ($('.remodal').scrollTop() > $("#anchor-point").offset().top) {
```

Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/5/

Comment: How come it only works on the first modal and not the next few? https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/6/

Comment: When doing $("#anchor-point").offset().top, JQuery selects the first matching element and uses it. When you're trying to use the second modal, as the first element matching $(".anchor-point").offset().top is not displayed, the condition won't work. What you should do is dynamically switch the element when clicking on the link. Have a look at this JSFiddle : jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/12 I associated each link with an anchor point using data attributes, and I dynamically switch the element when I click the links